# Deserialize JSON To LINQ-able Collection

Tags: c#, json, linq

Normally, deserializing isn't a challenge for me. Simple call to JSON.NET and TADA! But this particular deserialization is proving to be rather difficult. So the basic schema is as follows:

```
{"1" : {
    "name" : "Any Offers",
    "stattrak" : "0",
    "star" : "0",
    "souvenir" : "0",
    "sort" : "0",
    "exterior" : "0",
    "quality" : "0",
    "icon" : "",
    "worth" : 0,
    "betable" : 0
},
"2" : {
    "name" : "Real Money",
    "stattrak" : "0",
    "star" : "0",
    "souvenir" : "0",
    "sort" : "0",
    "exterior" : "0",
    "quality" : "0",
    "icon" : "",
    "worth" : 0,
    "betable" : 0
    }
}
```

Now without defining a MASSIVE class with 5000+ Keys I went the route of:

```
var schema = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,JToken>>(schemaString);
```

This provides me with the following (LINQPad Output):

[image]

How would I go about LINQ-ing against the values, such as find all JTokens with the value of "Any Offers". Am I just not nesting enough? Because I tried doing something along the lines of:

```
schema.Select(x => x.Value.Children().Children().Values().Where(n=>n......))
```

Which leaves me with:

[image]

Any help would be fanstastic.

TL;DR; Want to be able to search against values in the collection with LINQ and can't figure out the method syntax to do so.

Comment: I don't see that items in your dictionary have 5000 properties. And even if they are, you can just deserialize everything as `Dictionary<String, dynamic>`, that is easily "LINQable", though not very type safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was over-complicating the entire deal. The solution was the following:

```
schema.Select(x => x.Value["name"]);
```

This was confusing due to the nesting in LINQPad

Answer (score 3):

I would deserialize it to a concrete class and then use linq

```
public class Entry
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string stattrak { get; set; }
    public string star { get; set; }
    public string souvenir { get; set; }
    public string sort { get; set; }
    public string exterior { get; set; }
    public string quality { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
    public int worth { get; set; }
    public int betable { get; set; }
}

var schema = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,Entry>>(schemaString);
```

something like: `schema.Values.Where(x=>x.name=="...")`

Comment: Works flawlessly. I was using the `Dictionary<string,JToken>` because that's a requirement when using it within a class with `[JsonExtensionData]` but not when directly deserializing to that type. Thank you :)